# openstack-install Can't import Boot Images

Tags: juju, maas, openstack, landscape, openstack-autopilot

Trying openstack-install, http://www.ubuntu.com/download/cloud/install-ubuntu-openstack, on a Trusty server - hoping to get Openstack Juno going - but having problems with importing images. Install process proceeds up to "Importing MAAS boot images" and stalls thereon. Indeed /var/lib/maas/boot-resources is empty, and is properly noted in /var/log/maas/masslog:

```
...
Nov 19 19:02:37 openstack maas.tftp: [WARNING] No boot images have been imported from the region.
Nov 19 19:02:38 openstack maas.tftp: message repeated 3 times: [ [WARNING] No boot images have been imported from the region.]
Nov 19 19:02:39 openstack maas.import-images: [WARNING] Finished importing boot images, the region does not have any boot images available.
Nov 19 19:02:39 openstack maas.tftp: [WARNING] No boot images have been imported from the region.
...
```

Similar messages are seen in syslog:

```
...
Nov 19 19:07:37 openstack maas.tftp: [WARNING] No boot images have been imported from the region.
Nov 19 19:07:38 openstack maas.tftp: message repeated 3 times: [ [WARNING] No boot images have been imported from the region.]
Nov 19 19:07:39 openstack maas.import-images: [WARNING] Finished importing boot images, the region does not have any boot images available.
Nov 19 19:07:39 openstack maas.tftp: [WARNING] No boot images have been imported from the region.
Nov 19 19:08:08 openstack maas.bootresources: [INFO] Finished importing of boot images from 1 source(s).
...
```

I can ping maas.ubuntu.com and do wget:

```
root@openstack:~/.cloud-install# wget http://maas.ubuntu.com/images/ephemeral-v2/daily/
--2014-11-19 19:12:44--  http://maas.ubuntu.com/images/ephemeral-v2/daily/
Resolving maas.ubuntu.com (maas.ubuntu.com)... 91.189.90.19, 91.189.89.122
Connecting to maas.ubuntu.com (maas.ubuntu.com)|91.189.90.19|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 1940 (1.9K) [text/html]
Saving to: ‘index.html’

100%[======================================>] 1,940       --.-K/s   in 0s      

2014-11-19 19:12:44 (38.3 MB/s) - ‘index.html’ saved [1940/1940]
```

any thoughts?
Cheers,

Edit 1: OK... within couple of hours of the original posting, the instruction in the reference link changed! Will try again and report.

Comment: How did you get on? It looks from the syslog entries that you did indeed get boot images imported. Note that the image import process is two steps - first to import images on to the "region controller" and then that syncs to the "cluster controller". These will be on the same host on a normal install.

Comment: Unfortunately it kept timing out. I am trying the new instructions, however.

Comment: Check the router definition in Cluster interface